# php add inputs with same name to mysql

Tags: php

I have a form with some generated input fields like theese:

```
 <input value="March" name="month[March]" type="hidden"> 
<input value="April" name="month[April]" type="hidden"> 
<input value="May" name="month[May]" type="hidden">
```

I need to add the data from each input to mysql, but i don`t know how if they have name[monthname].The table structure is id, name and month_name. So i need to add the input data to month_name column. Thanks!

Comment: What's the database structure?

Comment: please add more to understand

Comment: Voting to close as too localized. You've got two questions going on here: one about duplicate GET or POST variable names, and one about inserting into MySQL.

Comment: To expand on Michael and Mayank's comments, [sample code](http://sscce.org/) is king. If you have a question that concerns databases, include appropriate SQL statements, such as the table schema (as `CREATE TABLE` statements) and (if appropriate) sample data (as `INSERT ... VALUES` statements). See [Writing the Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for more.

Comment: @DavidWolever, What do you think about my answer? Should be enough for such type of question, dont you think?

Comment: @Starx You give an admirable answer to half of the OP's question. However, the nature of the questions suggests to me that the OP is asking StackOverflow to write code for them (specifically, the “add the data into MySQL” bit)… And I believe that “write code for me” (or “do my thinking for me”) type questions should be discouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidWolever, Motion seconded. Closing from my side too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over different input with same name in this way

```
foreach($_POST['month'] as $value) {
   echo $value;
   //Use the value in the query, it gets April March may, one by one
}
```

<sub>**P.S:** Assuming you are using POST method to submit the form.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
<input value="March" name="month[March]" type="hidden"> 
<input value="April" name="month[April]" type="hidden"> 
<input value="May" name="month[May]" type="hidden">
```

You can add them separated by commas (or any other delimiter provided it does not create SQL injection). Like

```
<?php
$months = $_REQUEST['month'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `YOURTABLE` values ('$id','$name','";
$comma_flag = false;
foreach ($months as $month)
{
    $sql = $sql.($comma_flag?",":"").$month;
    $comma_flag = true;
}
$sql .="');";
$dbc = mysql('localhost','username','password');
mysql_select_db('your_database',$dbc);
mysql_query($sql,$dbc);
?>
```

Note: The MySQL Column `month_name` must be `varchar` of larger size.

Later if you want to retreive, after '`SELECT FROM ...` ' you can split it using

```
$months = explode($result,",");
```

Comment: The sample code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). Moreover, the mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements. Prepared statement parameters aren't vulnerable to injection.